# python gensim TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found

Tags: python, python-2.7, typeerror, iterable, gensim

So I believe despite this being a common issue with many similar questions (especially on stackoverflow), the main reason behind this issue varies in each case

In my case I have a method named `readCorpus` (**find code below**) it reads a list of 21 files, extract docs from each file then yield them

The yield operation occurs at the end of reading each file

I have another method named `uploadCorpus` (**find code below**). The main aim of this method is to upload that corpus.

Obviously the main reason behind using yield is that the corpus can be very large and I only need to read it once.

Once I run the method `uploadCorpus` I receive the error below

`TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found`

The erros occurs at the line `self.readCorpus()])`.

Reading similar problems I came to understand that it happens when a list is misplaced .. I tried to uplate the line of question here to `docs for docs in self.readCorpus()])` but I ended with the same issue

**My code (uploadCorpus)**

```
def uploadCorpus(self):
        #convert docs to corpus
        print "uploading"

        utils.upload_chunked(
            self.service,
            [{'id': 'doc_%i' % num, 'tokens': utils.simple_preprocess(doc)}
            for num, doc in enumerate([ 
                self.readCorpus()])
                ],
            chunksize=1000) # send 1k docs at a time
```

**My code readCorpus()**

```
def readCorpus(self):
    path = '../data/reuters'
    doc=''
    docs = []
    docStart=False

    fileCount=0

    print 'Reading Corpus'
    for name in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.sgm')):
        print 'Reading File| ' + name
        docCount=0
        for line in open(name):
            if(len(re.findall(r'<BODY>', line)) > 0 ): 
                docStart = True
                pattern = re.search(r'<BODY>.*', line)
                doc+= pattern.group()[6:]

            if(len(re.findall(r'</BODY>\w*', line)) > 0 ):
                docStart = False
                docs.append(doc)
                doc=''
                docCount+=1
                continue
                #break
            if(docStart):
                doc += line

        fileCount+=1
        print 'docuemnt[%d][%d]'%(fileCount,docCount)
        yield docs
        docs = []
```

Comment: Try wrapping `json.dumps` around your list in the uploads chunked function. This will convert your list to a string and make it compatible for upload.

Comment: @kpie I still got the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line below is expecting an iterable object .. where the `readCorpus` function was supposed to be a generator using the keyword `yield`

```
self.readCorpus()
```

However the `readCorpus` function was not behaving the way a generator is supposed to be because of a poor implementation of the `yield` keyword.

The current implementation yield an array of items every 1000 loop iterations while the correct way is yield item by item.

Hence the readCorpus needs to be modified as following

```
def readCorpus(self):
        path = '../data/reuters'
        doc=''
        docStart=False

        fileCount=0

        print 'Reading Corpus'
        for name in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.sgm')):
            print 'Reading File| ' + name
            docCount=0
            for line in open(name):
                if(len(re.findall(r'<BODY>', line)) > 0 ): 
                    docStart = True
                    pattern = re.search(r'<BODY>.*', line)
                    doc+= pattern.group()[6:]

                if(len(re.findall(r'</BODY>\w*', line)) > 0 ):
                    docStart = False
                    #docs.append(doc)
                    yield doc
                    doc=''
                    docCount+=1
                    continue
                    #break
                if(docStart):
                    doc += line

            fileCount+=1
            print 'docuemnt[%d][%d]'%(fileCount,docCount)
```